# Why is a function like $z^{2.5}$ not holomorph?

Tags: holomorphic-functions

If I consider the function $f(z)=z^{2.5}$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, it is continuously differentiable with $f'(z)=2.5z^{1.5}$. But  why can I not do the same in $\mathbb{C}$ with $ f'(z)=2.5z^{1.5}$?

Comment: What is $f(-1)$? Also, who says you can't?

Comment: $e^{2.5ln(-1)}$ and thats not defined?

Comment: What's $\ln(-1)$?

Comment: thats not defined

Comment: So there you have the problem with $f(-1)$. Why should the rest of the complex plane be any easier?

Comment: A more subtle question is why $f(a+bi)=a-bi$ is not holomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(z)=z^{2.5}$ is only well defined on positive real numbers. Everywhere else, you need to provide additional info. For example, it is not clear what $(-1)^{2.5}$ would be equal to.

You **could** write the function as $z^{2.5} = e^{2.5\cdot \log(z)}$, but then, the function $\log$ is not well defined on the complex numbers. Taking the standard logarithm, the function $\log$ is undefined in $(-\infty, 0]$, and there is no way you can ever continuously define the logarithm function on the entire complex plane.